# Replacing Nissan Qashqai 2L (2008) Bearing Kit - RE0F10A

Tags: automatic-transmission, nissan, bearing, pulley

I'm working on repairing the **automatic** transmission in a Nissan Qashqai 2008 (2L engine).

Specifically, trying to replace the transmission bearing (RE0F10A) using this kit:

https://www.ebay.com/itm/CVT-JF011E-RE0F10A-F1CJA-Transmission-Bearing-Kit-4-cylinder-CVT-bearing-/322531157198

I'm having a real difficult time figuring out how to disassemble and reach the actual bearing.  Can anyone here point me to a good illustrated manual or online video on how to reach that part?

Help is really appreciated!

Comment: This is a really technical job requiring special tools and a VERY high level of cleanliness and skill - your best option is to purchase the correct workshop manual from the dealer or take it to a transmission specialist IMHO

Comment: @SolarMike - Thanks. Is there somewhere online where I could purchase this manual?

Comment: Perhaps Nissan has an online shop...